# What is the meaning of, "Here's mud in your eye"?

Tags: expressions

What is the meaning of, "Here's mud in your eye"? 
Wikipedia reports a biblical connection, or WWI trench warfare, or horse racing. The O.E.D. says essentially the same. 
I understand it to be a reference to the particles of sediment at the bottom of a bottle of wine.

Comment: [*the **origin**, and indeed the meaning, of this particular glass-clinking salutation **is as clear as, well, mud***](https://www.funtrivia.com/askft/Question142153.html) But for all practical purposes, the ***meaning*** (what we mean when we say it) is a trivial issue you could easily look up.

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done (some is easy to find); the origin of the phrase and any meaning beyond 'cheers / good health' seem hard to ascertain.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP explicitly mentions his research

Comment: @Arm the good guys in America Dan Bron has said: '[ELU requires] a demonstration of effort on behalf of the OP. Effort on par with the effort OP would like potential answerers to demonstrate.' And MετάEd: 'This answer was ... flagged as low-quality because of its length / content.  A good answer is comprehensive and contains evidence showing why it is correct. Links to external resources are encouraged. Answers which consist of virtually nothing but an unsupported statement or a citation are not useful and may be subject to deletion – even correct answers.'  Here, linked/attributed quotes.

Comment: The recommended list of resources includes [The Phrase Finder](https://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/23/messages/349.html), probably the first port of call for phrase meanings and origins. Had this been offered, FumbleFingers might well have given an 'answer' using the reference he's dug up: Meaning, health to our friends (and not to others); origins, unclear.